# Jack, Jill, and Jake build a 1-manifold. Who's doing it correctly?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, manifolds

A question to help me clarify some terminology and basic topological concepts.

Suppose we consider the line $y = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ as a continuous $1$-manifold with boundary in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which we denote as $L$.

Jack, Jill, and Jake want to define this manifold in three different ways. **Jack** takes the function $$f(n) = (\pi^n \operatorname{mod} 1,\pi^n \operatorname{mod} 1) \;\;\forall\;n \in \mathbb{N}$$ and says, "Look. Every value of $n$ yields a different point on the line $y = x$, and the set of all values $\pi^n \operatorname{mod} 1$ is dense in $[0,1]$, hence the image of $f$ over $\mathbb{N}$ is the manifold we want.

"True, a $1$-manifold is supposed to 'look like' $\mathbb{R}$ locally, and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable while the image of $f$ is countable. However, we can still consider the image of $f$ to be the required manifold since, for example, if we were to plot values of $f$, then to *any finite resolution we require*, we can make the plot 'look like' the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, i.e. $L$. Furthermore, if we want to compute the tangent space of the manifold, we can compute it at any point to *any finite degree of precision we require*. Hence, notwithstanding angels dancing on the heads of pins, there's nothing we can do with $L$ that we can't also do with the image of $f$."

**Jill** says, "This doesn't seem right to me. For a set to 'look like' $\mathbb{R}$ locally, it has to have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, meaning it has to be a true continuum. Hence I propose defining a set-valued function $$g(n) = \{(t,t),\;t = (\pi^n+s)\operatorname{mod} 1;\;s\in[0,\epsilon]\}$$ where $\epsilon$ is any positive real value, and then constructing the set $L' = \{(1,1)\}\cup\bigcup_n g(n)$. Then clearly $L'$ 'looks like' $\mathbb{R}$ locally and is a manifold equivalent to $L$. What you're describing, Jack, is a only a *Jackset*.

**Jake** says, "You're wrong too, Jill. You can't just consider a set of points to be a $1$-manifold, even if those points can be diffeomorphically mapped to an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. For the set of points to truly constitute a manifold, it must also have the *Jake Property*. What you're describing, Jill, is only a *Jillset*."

---

My present understanding is that *Jill* is correct here. That is, a countable set of points cannot be the $1$-manifold $L$, even if the set is dense and lies entirely within $L$; however, Jill's covering-of-sets construction is, in fact, a manifold equal to $L$. Nothing else is required.

**My questions:**

1. Is Jill in fact correct? Or is Jack? Or is Jake?
2. Assuming Jack is wrong, what is the proper terminology for a "Jackset"?
3. Assuming Jake is correct, what is the proper terminology for "Jillset", and what is/are the "Jake properties" needed to make the set into a true manifold?